# RegEx expression to remove duplicate word groups

Tags: regex

I am trying to remove duplicate values from the following text:

```
[John Smith][John Smith][Jane Doe][Jane Doe][Doe][John][Smith John][John Smith Sr]
```

However, I need to treat each group of words inside the brackets as a unique value. That way, if a single word appears inside multiple brackets, but the group of words inside the brackets differ, I keep all values.

Using my sample text I expect to get the below,

```
[John Smith][Jane Doe][Doe][John][Smith John][John Smith Sr]
```

But instead I get the following text when using this RegEx `(?:\[)(.+)(?:\])(?=.*\b\1,?)`

```
[Jane Doe][Doe][Smith John][John Smith Sr]
```

Where am I going wrong? Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Are you using Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture each encountered square-braced substring, then check if that same substring occurs again later in the string -- if so, replace it.

`(\[[^]]+])(?=.*\1)`

Using a negated character class (`[^]]`) allows the use of a greedy quantifier `+` without "over-matching" -- this means that the regex won't waste time trying to match multiple consecutive square braces later in the string before backtracking to smaller potential matches.

https://regex101.com/r/OD1hia/1

If using javascript or another environment that requires escaping the closing brace in the negated character class, add a slash there.

https://regex101.com/r/Wm3K4f/1

There will be many duplicates of this technique on Stack Overflow, but I didn't find an exact "snowflake" duplicate that requires the square braces.

Comment: Notice that in JS this regex won't work (you should escape the inner braket with `[^\]]`).

Comment: There is absolutely no distinction of what environment this technique is going to be implemented in.  Once this is clarified, I'll be able to add escaping characters as needed.

Comment: I am using a low-code software, hence why i did not specify, nonetheless, it worked for my particular scenario     thanks  mickmackusa

Comment: Was I clear about why `.+` will use extra effort to try to match `[John Smith][John Smith][Jane Doe][Jane Doe][Doe][John][Smith John][John Smith Sr]` then `[John Smith][John Smith][Jane Doe][Jane Doe][Doe][John][Smith John]` then `[John Smith][John Smith][Jane Doe][Jane Doe][Doe][John]` then `[John Smith][John Smith][Jane Doe][Jane Doe][Doe]` ... and on and on before it finds a small enough duplicate then it creeps forward and repeats?  The greedy quanitifier on the dot will work from longest to short possibilities.  My answer ONLY checks for individual braced substrings as it traverses. @Sen

Comment: My answer checks: `[John Smith]` then `[John Smith]` then `[Jane Doe]` then `[Jane Doe]` then `[Doe]` then `[John]` then `[Smith John]` then `[John Smith Sr]` ONLY.  @Sen

Comment: This answer prevents unnecessary backtracking ++

Answer (score 2):

You have to capture also the squared brakets in the first group:

```
(\[.+\])(?=.*\1)
```

In this way you ensure to check the duplicates w.r.t. the whole brakets' content.